# ggplot2: how to mark days when event occurred

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get information from the second plot onto the first one.

[image: Plot 1]

The second plot represents days when an event occurred. It seems wider because it does not have a legend, but it is the same timescale. I chose to assign colours manually in the first plot.

I would like to overlay the second plot dots/symbols on the first plot (i.e. combine them) so that the events can be seen in one plot. Ideally this would be a line of dots that is at 0.33 height on Y and at the right end it would have letter F marking the dots - at the same height of 0.33. Could you help with that? Data and plot code are below:
[image: Plot 2]

**Plot 1:**

```
ggplot(dfSub, aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=P,col='P'),span=0.5,se=F) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=A,col='A'),span=0.5, se=F) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=DEP,col='DEP'),span=0.5, se=F) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=R,col='R'),stat="identity",alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual("",
                     values=c('P'='red','A'='purple','DEP'='blue',R='grey')) +
  ylab("Scale 0 to 4")
```

**Plot 2:**

```
ggplot(dfSub, aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_point(data=subset(dfSub, !is.na(F)), aes(y=F))
```

**Data:**

```
dfSub <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17539, 17540, 17541, 17542, 
17543, 17544, 17545, 17546, 17547, 17548, 17549, 17550, 17551, 
17552, 17553, 17554, 17555, 17556, 17557, 17558, 17559, 17560, 
17561, 17562, 17563, 17564, 17565, 17566, 17567, 17568, 17569, 
17570, 17571, 17572, 17573, 17574, 17575, 17576, 17577, 17578, 
17579, 17580, 17581, 17582, 17583, 17584, 17585, 17586, 17587, 
17588, 17589, 17590, 17591, 17592, 17593, 17594, 17595, 17596, 
17597, 17598, 17599, 17600, 17601, 17602, 17603, 17604, 17605, 
17606, 17607, 17608, 17609, 17610, 17611, 17612, 17613, 17614, 
17615, 17616, 17617, 17618, 17619, 17620, 17621, 17622, 17623, 
17624, 17625, 17626, 17627, 17628, 17629), class = "Date"), R = c(1, 
2, NA, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
2, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), 
    P = c(2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 
    2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, NA, 2, NA, 4, 4, 1, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), F = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), .Label = "X", class = "factor"), DEP = c(NA, NA, 1.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.5, NA, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 
    1, 1, 1.5, 1, 2, 2, 1.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
    1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 
    NA, 2, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 
    2, 1, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 1, 2, 2), A = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), FAS = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), .Label = "X", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", "R", 
"P", "F", "DEP", "A", "FAS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-91L))
```

Comment: What did you try? Just add to your first plot `+ geom_point(data=subset(dfSub, !is.na(F)), y = 0.33)` You can use `annotate` to add the "F" wherever you want.

Comment: Great, thanks, I did not think of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

pp1 <- ggplot(dfSub, aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=P,col='P'),span=0.5,se=F) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=A,col='A'),span=0.5, se=F) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=DEP,col='DEP'),span=0.5, se=F) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=R,col='R'),stat="identity",alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual("",
                 values=c('P'='red','A'='purple','DEP'='blue',R='grey')) +
  ylab("Scale 0 to 4")

dfSub <- dfSub %>% 
  mutate(F1 = ifelse(F == "X", 0.33, .))

pp1 + 
  geom_point(data=subset(dfSub, !is.na(F1)), aes(y=F1)) +
  geom_text(data = dfSub %>% 
          select(Date, F1) %>% 
          arrange(desc(Date)) %>% 
          slice(1), 
        aes(x = Date + 0.03, y = 0.33, label = "F"))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what the chain `select %>% arrange %>% slice` means? I sort of understand, but explanation would help. I imagine slice selects 1 element?

Comment: That part you want to find the last `Date` on the `x-axis` then add `0.03` to it to place the label "F": select only `Date` & `F1` columns, sort `Date` by descending order then get only the latest one using `slice`

Answer (score 4):

First off, I think you'll have an easier time if you reshape your data into a long format instead of a wide one. `ggplot` expects long shaped data. That way you can map aesthetics--in your case, color--to a variable, and then call `geom_smooth` once instead of multiple times.

Also just as a simplification, `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

@Gregor's suggestion above is good: if you only need one or two pieces of text, an `annotate` call is pretty simple. In this case, I did it with `x = max(df_long$Date), y = 0.33`, but you could place it at any date you want.

Let me know if any of this isn't clear.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# deleted long line of reading in data frame
df_long <- dfSub %>%
    select(-FAS) %>%
    mutate(`F` = as.numeric(`F`)) %>%
    gather(key = group, value = value, -Date) %>%
    filter(!is.na(value))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Date, group = group)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(y = value, color = group), data = . %>% filter(group %in% c("P", "A", "DEP")), span = 0.5, se = F) +
    geom_col(aes(y = value), data = . %>% filter(group == "R"), alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey") +
    geom_point(aes(color = "F"), y = 0.33, data = . %>% filter(group == "F")) +
    annotate("text", x = max(df_long$Date), y = 0.33, label = "F") +
    scale_color_manual("", values = c("P" = "red", "A" = "purple", "DEP" = "blue", "F" = "gray30")) +
    ylab("Scale 0 to 4")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

**Added 4/29**: For the dots, here's an example of using data where the y value isn't just hardcoded, as the original post had.

```r
set.seed(1234)
dots <- data.frame(
    value = rep(c(0.5, 1, 1.5), each = 20),
    Date = sample(unique(df_long$Date), size = 60, replace = T)
)


ggplot() +
    geom_col(
        aes(x = Date, y = value),
        data = df_long %>% filter(group == "R"),
        fill = "gray60"
    ) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = value), data = dots)
```

Comment: It is slightly confusing about long data - when you do that, do you always subset the main data frame to one which contains only values for the plot and then melt/gather on the variable for `Y` axis?

Comment: Not necessarily, but prepping your data how you want it before trying to plot anything will help reduce problems in plotting. Filtering in this case was only needed because you wanted to split categories for the different types of geoms

Comment: This is really good. I used this for my final visualization and it works very well. I had 5 more variables like `F`. Hence I had quite a bit of repetition in the plot code - I had to repeat `geom_point` and `annotate` lines 5 more times (and of course put more colours in the manual scale). But repetition was necessary because I needed to plot the rows of points at about 0.15 spacing on Y axis. To accommodate the rows I extended the plot downwards a bit. I wonder if one would write a function for the extra variables? Or just not bother since this is the final output?

Comment: If you needed to do something like the dots above, you could just put in a y value also. I'll amend my answer with a dummy example

Comment: Great, I got the idea. It is easy indeed, I just need to set values for the relevant groups in the long data frame. Thank you.